# Card game probability question?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, card-games, bayes-theorem

A person selects 2 cards without replacement from a standard deck of cards. What is the probability that he select a heart, given that he has selected a face card?

So my solution is P(getting a heart|getting a face card) = 13/52

is that correct?

Comment: Your answer is correct. One needs some justification. Also there is some ambiguity in the question. Was selection in order, meaning probability second is a heart given first was face card? Or are we asking for the probability of at least one heart given we have at least one face card?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The events of a card being a face card and a card being a heart are independent. So does it really matter that the first chosen card is a face card?